# OpenCV Restrict Face Detection Only in Correct Orientation

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am working on a project which requires face detection in image. I am using Haar Cascading 'frontal face'.

I want to limit face detection to detect face only when the image in portait mode. Not to detect face when image is rotated left, right or upside down. I have been searching for days to limit face detection only in portrait mode but I am not able to do so.

I am reading 'exif' information from images which have it and rotate images based of exif rotation. But if I manually rotate images, its exif information will not be change. So I have to rotate image and detect face until I find the face. Face Detection algorithm does not limit itself to the orientation.

My question is if the image is portait and it is dis-oriented or image is landscape and it is dis-oriented, how to limit algorithm to rotate and detect face with correct oriented output image.

I am working in OpenCV in Java. Will implement same in Android and iOS.

What I Want.

[image: What i Want]

What I am Getting.

[image: What I am getting after rotating]

**Edit**

**Algorithm**

- Folder is given to program
- Read all images from folder and add them to list.
- Make a new thread and pass image to it.
- Detect face.
- If not succesful, rotate again and detect again.
- If succesful, terminate thread.
- Do for all the images.

The program is suppose to rotate image in correct orientation if image is dis-oriented, depending on face detection to let the user view picture in state he will not have to rotate image manually.

Comment: simple is don't apply face detection algorithm if image is rotated.

Comment: I am applying algorithm on the images to let them in correct orientation. _ets say there are hundres of pictures in the folder which are dis-oriented. I have to get them in corret orientation. So initially I don't know of the image is rotated or not. I have to apply algorithm to find face and get them in correct orientation. How to know if image is rotated?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's face detector is "orientation sensitive", meaning that it will detect mostly up-right faces. If the image has the correct orientation, you should get more faces detected and with higher confidence.

Comment: Above image is just for example. I am reading a folder which can have multiple images. Its not necessary if image have multiple faces. And the program don't know what is the current orientation of image it is reading. I am saying that OpenCV face detector still detects face even if the image is already rotated clockwise or counter-clockwise. I have to get picture in correct orientation.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question then. I thought you wanted to use face detection results to guess the correct orientation of the image.

Comment: I have added algorithm I am following. Please see edit.

Comment: You may try doing the face detection for the four possible orientations and then compute an "up-right score" for each one of them based on the number and confidence of detected faces.

Comment: And what about the image that will have only one face? How to eliminate error probability if there is only one face and algorithm detects it in wrong orientation? I mean if image is rotated left or right and it detects face in wrong orientation?

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

For each detected face:

- use haar cascade to detect left and right eye and compare their locations.

Now you will be able to check if the detected face is in the right orientation.